# How can Purusha be God when he was sacrificed to bring about creation?

Tags: purusha

From

http://www.indicstudies.us/Hinduism/SelectSacredTexts/purusha_sukta.htm

text 7:

> saptasyasan paridhayaha
>
> trissapta samidhah kritaha
>
> deva yadjajnam tanvanaha
>
> abadhnan purusham pashum
>
> For this (yajna or spiritual ceremony) there were seven paridhis (fuel >pieces serving as borders). And, twenty-one items were made the samit or >sacrificial fuel sticks. When the devas were performing this yajna or >ceremony, they tied the purusha (himself) as the pashu (sacrificial animal).

Comment: Just write '>saptasyasan' instead of 'saptasyasan' and see what happens.

Comment: done; is that good?  @rohit

Comment: Yo, finally you made it. ;)

Comment: Similarly, put '>For' instead of 'For'. <BR> to break the line before For.

Comment: @Rohit Haha he is making a mess of ur tutorials .. now it's > at many places

Comment: Please see [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for editing help. It is not hard.

Answer (score 1):

Isn’t it that there is only one Purusha in the transcendent plane, who appears as many Purushas in the phenomenal plane.

According to Tirumular purusa is only a product of maya.

Tirumandiram 408: The Act of Genesis.

The One Lord and the goodly two (Maya Saktis)

Together stirred and Commingled the Family Impure (of matter) 
The Two then besought of the Lord:

"What shall we make? Command us, O Lord"

And the Lord Himself then spells them out.

Comment: Yup, According to [Kashmiri Shaivism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kashmir_Shaivism), Tantras, Agamas etc also there is one Purusha (1st tattva) appears as many in phenomenal plane (12th Tattva).  Read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tattva_(Shaivism)).